# how to show variable value in Xcode's debug inspector

Tags: xcode, debugging

New to Xcode, but I want to check the value of variables in Xcode's inspector, like following, `buttonFrame` has `origin` and `size` property, but they are not displayed in the inspector, is there a way to show that?

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The real solution here is using debug mode instead of release mode to build the app to the device, to change the mode:

```
project -> scheme -> check the target -> edit scheme -> run -> select the debug mode in the drop-down selector
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `po` command as described in apple's documentation:

According to apple:

> Print Description of “{variable}”. An equivalent to using po in the
>   console or using the Print Description button in a tool tip.

[XCode Debugging Tools](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/DeveloperTools/Conceptual/debugging_with_xcode/chapters/debugging_tools.html)

But keep in mind, that if you don't see values for the button's frame and size, it could be that they haven't been set yet. Make sure that the break point you are using to inspect these variables is being set at a point in your code in which you are certain the view has been laid out `viewDidAppear` for example.

Comment: hi, thanks, it's wired because the NSLog before the break point has already printed the right variable value, but I don't want to print all the variable I want to inspect, cause it's inconvinent

Comment: yeah, I've had a lot of issues with XCode debugging, not working exactly as I expected. I guess we need to be patient while Apple works on improving it for the next XCode release.

Comment: LOL, did we have other choices?